# Display a custom field after product description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_description_tab', 'aq_display_disclaimer', 40, 9);

function aq_display_disclaimer() {
  echo '<b>Disclaimer:</b> ' . get_field('product_disclaimer');
}
```

I am trying to display a WYSIWYG field on frontend but it is not displaying for some reason. I also tried to use other functions like product_summary and before and after the_content and it works great.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Ahmed Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [`woocommerce_product_description_tab`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_product_description_tab.html#1257-1265) **it's not a hook** but a function that is [triggered as a callback](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_product_description_tab.html#1291) for Product description tab. 
>   It loads the template `single-product/tabs/description.php`, **and you can't use it** to add your product disclaimer.

Now the template `single-product/tabs/description.php` use `the_content()` Wordpress function to display the product description and you can add your disclaimer after it using `the_content` filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'display_disclaimer_after_product_description', 10, 1 );
function display_disclaimer_after_product_description( $content ){
    // Only for single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return $content;

    if( $product_disclaimer = get_field( 'product_disclaimer', get_the_id() ) )
        return $content . '<b>Disclaimer:</b> ' . $product_disclaimer;

    return $content;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

If you want to replace the product description with that disclaimer, you will replace this line:

```
return $content . '<b>Disclaimer:</b> ' . $product_disclaimer;
```

by the following one:

```
return '<b>Disclaimer:</b> ' . $product_disclaimer;
```

Comment: Thank you Loic. I placed my code under tabs templates in description.php but this method is very nice maybe I would like to move this functions.php 

Thank you again for your time. :)